# Prune full node recovery after 1 month of inactivity

Tags: pruning

Alice is running a prune full node (around 7GB) of storage for prune node. It was working fine

Due to power outrages, Alice prune full node was shutdown for 1 month.

can this full prune node recover and be operational just by downloading those missing blocks.
Or Alice has to download and verify everything again starting from the genesis block.

Comment: What is the problem? Does the node not work anymore?

Comment: i cannot access the lab due to movement control!

Answer (score 3):

Alice will be able to download just the missing blocks, since her node has already validated the blockchain up until that point. However she will need to synchronize from an unpruned node, since pruned nodes aren't usually storing blocks that are a month old.

Answer (score 2):

Nodes don't stop working after being offline, regardless of how long, and regardless of whether they're pruned or not.

After some amount of time (a few days at most), nodes cannot synchronize from other pruned nodes anymore, but that's ok; there are plenty of non-pruned nodes.